# Can merge replication operate with 0 ms delay, i.e. be real-time?

Tags: sql-server, database, replication, merge-replication

I'm facing an issue that I have two identical databases on different servers and both working as read/write and data are inserted on both. The thing is there is a merge replication between the two databases and it's working fine but there is a minute delay until the data is synchronized. What I want is to remove this delay. I want the data to be synchronized immediately.

What kind of solutions can I apply? Is there another feature like replication but without delay, or can I make the replication work without a delay, i.e. to be real-time. Any suggestion please. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to achieve 0 ms delay or real-time with any type of Replication.

You can configure the Merge Agent to run continuously which will replicate changes every 60 seconds by default.  This delay can be decreased by specifying a lower value for the -PollingInterval parameter which is how often in seconds the publisher or subscriber is queried for changes. For more information on the PollingInterval parameter see [Replication Merge Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/agents/replication-merge-agent).

Depending on your requirements, Transactional Replication may be a better fit as it is near real time.